# The link button is not shown as selected (lacking color border)

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-5, angular-routing

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{title}}!!
  </h1>
  <nav>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
          <a routerLink="home" routerLinkActive="active"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
              Home</button></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <a routerLink="about"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
              About</button></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-1">
          <a routerLink="dashboard"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
              Dashboard</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I have a routing app with three navigation link buttons(home/about/dashboard). I am using Bootstrap 5.
My app.component.html looks like this:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{title}}!!
  </h1>
  <nav>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
          <a routerLink="home" routerLinkActive="active"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
              Home</button></a>
              
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <a routerLink="about"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
              About</button></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-1">
          <a routerLink="dashboard"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
              Dashboard</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

My `about.component.ts` looks like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent {

}
```

The other two components look very similar.

My `app-routing.module.ts` looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutComponent
  },
  { path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent
  }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I expected that when I click on one of the link buttons, it will appear with the border color changed indicating that it is selected.
. No matter which button you click none of them is shown as selected (with the border color changed).

Comment: Your example link is broken. Is there relevant CSS? Why do you have buttons nested within anchors?

Comment: Buttons nested inside of anchors is invalid HTML and will cause unwanted side effects. I tend to go with anchors if there is navigation involved, and with buttons when it triggers functionality on the page.

Comment: Even if I get rid of buttons nested in anchors it still does not work

Comment: Your stackBlitz  link is broken. None of the code posted here will change the border color. Please post a minimal reproducible example here, preferably as a stack snippet, so we can have all pieces of the puzzle.

Comment: I have updated with the example of the three buttons

Comment: What are you expecting? To change the border of the button depending on the router state or just after the clink when the button (should) get the focus event?

Comment: I would expect that after the button is clicked it's border is changed to reflect that it is actually selected. The way it is shown at the [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/)

Comment: in your code you use latest BS version (v5.2) which doesn't have that effect on button, and the docs link you provide uses older BS version (v5.0), so,use the older version (@5.0.2)